# PrismaClientValidationError "Unknown arg `order_by`" when field is valid, and ordering on other fields works

Tags: mysql, prisma, netlify, netlify-function

I'm trying out Netlify functions and have successfully written a function that uses Prismaclient to grab data from my Railway.app database.

I can view the database with Heidisql as well and confirm the order_by column exists and use it to select and order the results

```
SELECT id, name, order_by
FROM subsection
ORDER BY order_by ASC
```

I have a few api endpoints that list types of media, franchises, sections, then subsections (e.g. game > uncharted > uncharted 2: among thieves > a list of chapters)

When I serve my app locally with `npx netlify dev`, I can browse the site locally and visit the netlify function URL, and I get data back: http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/api?type=game&franchise=uncharted&section=uncharted%3A+drake%27s+fortune&resource=subsection

If I deploy that URL and visit it at the deployed site, I get this error in the Netlify function logs:

```
Jan 1, 05:34:43 PM: cabcab16 ERROR  PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.section.findMany()` invocation in
/var/task/functions/api.js:38:33

  35     type,
  36     franchise
  37 ) => {
→ 38     return await prisma.section.findMany({
           where: {
             franchise: {
               name: {
                 equals: 'uncharted'
               },
               type: {
                 name: {
                   equals: 'game'
                 }
               }
             }
           },
           orderBy: [
             {
               order_by: 'asc'
               ~~~~~~~~
             }
           ]
         })

Unknown arg `order_by` in orderBy.0.order_by for type sectionOrderByWithRelationInput. Available args:

type sectionOrderByWithRelationInput {
  id?: SortOrder
  franchise_id?: SortOrder
  name?: SortOrder
  slug?: SortOrder
  description?: SortOrder
  subsection_name?: SortOrder
  subsections?: subsectionOrderByRelationAggregateInput
  franchise?: franchiseOrderByWithRelationInput
}


    at Document.validate (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:32409:20)
    at serializationFn (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35993:19)
    at runInChildSpan (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:25431:12)
    at PrismaClient._executeRequest (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:36000:31)
    at applyQueryExtensions (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34331:19)
    at consumer (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35924:18)
    at /var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35929:51
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at /var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35929:29
    at runInChildSpan (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:25431:12) {
  clientVersion: '4.7.1'
}
```

Both sites (local deploy and Netlify deploy) are using the same Railway.app connection string, they can both select and query other data, but as soon as I try and use the `order_by` field live, it fails.

This is my Prismaschema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model subsection {
  id                  BigInt  @id @unique(map: "id") @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedBigInt
  name                String  @db.Text
  description         String? @db.Text
  order_by            Int     @default(0) @db.UnsignedInt
  section_id          BigInt  @default(0) @db.UnsignedBigInt
  section             section @relation(fields: [section_id], references: [id], map: "fk_subsection_section")

  @@index([section_id], map: "fk_subsection_section")
}

model section {
  id                BigInt      @id @unique(map: "id") @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedBigInt
  franchise_id      BigInt      @default(0) @db.UnsignedBigInt
  name              String      @db.Text
  slug              String?     @db.Text
  description       String?     @db.Text
  order_by          Int         @default(0) @db.UnsignedInt
  subsection_name   String?     @db.Text
  subsections       subsection[]
  franchise         franchise   @relation(fields: [franchise_id], references: [id], map: "fk_section_franchise")

  @@index([franchise_id], map: "fk_section_franchise")
}

model franchise {
  id           BigInt   @id @unique(map: "id") @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedBigInt
  name         String   @db.Text
  slug         String?  @db.Text
  type_id      BigInt   @default(0) @db.UnsignedBigInt
  description  String?  @db.Text
  section_name String?  @db.Text
  sections     section[]
  type         type     @relation(fields: [type_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "fk_franchise_type")

  @@index([type_id], map: "fk_series_type")
}

model type {
  id              BigInt   @id @unique(map: "id") @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedBigInt
  name            String   @db.Text
  slug            String?  @db.Text
  subsection_name String?  @db.Text
  section_name    String?  @db.Text
  has_subsections Boolean? @default(true)
  franchises      franchise[]
}
```

This is my first time using Prisma and Netlify functions, so please be gentle

If anyone can help my identify why it fails live or shed any light on how I can debug it live, I'd be greatful.

I've tried these and they all fail:

- changing order_by to a string
- changing order_by to a different column name
- adding new column names

Weirdly, I can swap the order by to "Descrpition" and it works, and some calls (for Type and Franchise) are already using "Name" for the orderBy and that works

Comment: I've moved the order_by logic into the app to get the netlify function to work without erroring, and am now selecting all fields, but weirdly netlify's deployment just doesn't return the order_by field in the JSON

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this, the Prisma.schema changes weren't being seen in the netlify deployment, until I used "Clear cache and deploy".

[image]

There's a post in the netlify support forums talking about how things outside the lambda handler function aren't re-run on following calls, which I guess includes checking the latest db schema.
https://answers.netlify.com/t/netlify-function-cache/70452/3

Comment: I encountered the same issue on vercel, redeploying solved it.